# What is the code for cubic spline regression model in SAS

Tags: regression, sas, outliers, splines

I ran an experiment that identified lame and non-lame cows every day for 325 days from a pool of 936 cows in one herd. At the same time, I collected data on various variables like milk volume, fat and protein % of the milk, weight of each cow, etc., daily on individual cows. I have read various papers and the one that analysed the data the closest to what I need to do, found outliers first, and then fit a nonparametric cubic spline regression model for each cow. He used days in milk as a single smoothing variable. How do I identify which are the outliers and how do I code it in SAS?

Comment: Not sure what's 'only' about being a PhD student, that's usually hard work.

Comment: What is your response variable? Are you trying to identify which cows will be lame? If so, you will need a classification model, like logistic regression, as opposed to regular regression. In addition, you will need to account for the serial correlation in your data.

Comment: hi there. thanks. I wrote "only" as im quite basic stats knowledge compared with all you guys. :)

Comment: HI there. thanks. I already have the cows identified as lame and not lame. I need to clean my data now by identifying which are my outliers, for example, I have some cows that have either missing information, or very extreme values for milk yield , weight, etc...

Comment: This appears to be a request for code...it might help to clarify question to emphasis statistical question.